# 12V power point socket keeps burning out, apparently from power surge

Tags: dc, 12v, solar-energy

I have a simple solar power setup:

- 40 watt panel with built-in charge controller (https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/coleman-40w-folding-solar-panel-0112043p.0112043.html)
- 12V marine battery (https://www.magnacharge.com/part/Magnacharge/Vehicle+Battery/24DC-140/)
- 12V power point socket w/fuse (https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/bluehive-12v-outlet-0374564p.html)
- 5V USB socket adapter (https://www.walmart.com/ip/onn-Dual-Port-Car-Charging-Kit-with-USB-C-to-USB-Cable-Black/592796333)

I have had various issues with the power socket. It seems that it may be drawing too much power at times.

Usually it is fine, but sometimes the socket, charging cords, and accessories being charged will get extremely hot, and I have also received an alert on my phone a few times that the charging voltage is too high.

I had a previous socket that was unfused, and one day it started sparking and got extremely hot, and could have started a fire, so I replaced it with the fused socket, but am still having problems.

The fuse did eventually burn out, but before it did, I had these heat and voltage issues several times where it did not burn out the fuse.

Am I missing a component in my system?

Comment: Impossible to say, as we don't know what the components are that you are currently using and whether they are suitable to what you use them.

Comment: Don’t use those cigar lighter type sockets. There are other better 12v sockets and plugs available.

Comment: @Justme I have added links to product descriptions for the components of my system. It's used to charge small accessories like phone, tablet, headlamp, etc.

Comment: @Solar Mike can you recommend a better socket? I just need USB ports. This is my only power source.

Comment: I can recommend what I would use, but who knows if they are available where you are. Check out what is available locally and then consider if you want to order online with the shipping delay.

Comment: they have potted (waterproof) dedicated 12v wired to 5v USB buck converters for a few bucks, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you need to look at voltage.

- For the 12V battery, they make [modules](https://www.autozone.com/gauges-and-gauge-accessories/amp-volt-gauge/p/dorman-help-12-volt-dc-digital-voltmeter-gauge/855835_0_0) you can install that will give you a continuous readout of voltage (and current for some devices).
- For 5V USB, they make ["in-line" modules](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2690) that read out both current and voltage.

You need to watch these voltages to see what is going wrong.

If battery voltage is above 14.5 volts, then that is a problem with the solar charge controller.

If USB voltage is above 5.2 volts, then you have a problem with the USB charger.

If USB current is above 2.2 amps, then it is a naughty load which is drawing too much from the USB charger.  Read its instructions and make sure you're using it with the correct charger.